# Should we close a question that can't be answered?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Today I saw a question that could not be answered.  I basically boils down to:

> In `Foo<something> function_name(Foo<something_else> parameter_name)` I am unable to identify `Foo`.  It is not defined in my code base.  Can you tell me what it is?

It is not a standard type and we do not have their code base so we can't tell them what it is.  I know it qualifies for down votes as it is not useful but I'm not sure if it should be closed.  We don't have a reason for this so I'm leaning towards it is okay to have a question we can't answer but that seems strange since we want quality question and answers.

Is there a close reason we can use or should we leave it alone?

Comment: off topic why isn't this working. The question doesn't provide the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and** the shortest code necessary to reproduce it

Comment: oh.. hmm... this isn't a debugging question... it's a What is x question?

Comment: @KevinB Exactly.  The OP doesn't get an error.  They just don't know what `Foo` is and they would like to know.

Comment: If that's the whole question, i'd lean toward unclear, if any at all

Comment: @KevinB It basically is.  I can link to the question if needed but I was trying to avoid the meta effect if possible.

Comment: to me it seems like it could be asking why Foo is undefined when it is used, or, what it means in that code context. and, which Foo? If the question is properly tagged, it very well could be a question that is usefully answered if it's just asking about the code syntax of defining methods.

Comment: Answer to original question - compile and then see what is referenced as "Foo" or use your IDE navigation tools to "go to definition" for "Foo".

Comment: How do these devs get by without knowing how to grep for references to missing stuff?

Comment: Too Broad, too many possible answers (every bit of code on the internet that produces Foo) or scope too broad (we have no idea what Foo really is in this context or where it comes from). I suppose someone who has used that specific Foo before may be able to recognize the specific Foo by how it is used, but that's probably a long shot at best.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Can you flag the question? I'd like to see it. (Assuming another mod doesn't get to your flag first, but you could always say that it's for me...)

Comment: @BoltClock Done.  Messed up the flag though.  Said Brad not Bolt.  Sorry about that

Comment: I don't see why a custom close reason couldn't be used here. The question could either be answered with "Foo is not a pre-defined type and it is not possible to determine its origin or meaning with just the given code.", or closed with the custom reason "This question cannot be answered as it is not possible to determine the origin or meaning of Foo with just the given code." Why is everybody trying to shoehorn the question into one of the pre-defined close reasons by cherry-picking specific clauses? Situations like this are what custom close reasons were *made* for.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks.  I was leaning that way but wasn't sure if it should actually be closed since as you said, there is at least one valid answer: We don't know. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: This doesn't seem appropriate, given that (as far as we know) the code *is* working.  I'd lean towards "not clear what you're asking" if there's insufficient information to answer.

Comment: @TobySpeight there's more to this close reason than that. *"Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."* and *"shortest code necessary to reproduce [it] in the question itself"*

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the question can be made useful by rewording

> Can you tell me what it is?

to

> I'm using IDE xyz, how can I find the declaration of `Foo`?

Maybe there's already a duplicate for it, if not it could be useful to have an answer for that.

Comment: This implies that the meaning is already clear, which is not. We would be guessing what OP means just for the sake of finding a duplicate, which wouldn't be useful anyways.

Comment: I have not seen the original. Of course it depends on how much "bending" is required to bring the question into shape. But this meta-question does not hint at too much unclarity IMO.

Comment: Oh, and also: If the original question would be excessively unclear, "unclear what you're asking" would be the obvious close reason, and this meta-q would not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Questions that cannot be answered by anyone but the person with access to the code base are not meaningful and should always be closed, since such questions have zero value to anyone but the OP.

Close as "cannot be reproduced":

> **This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

It is not terribly important which close reason to pick. If the present ones feel insufficient, you can use a custom close reason (off-topic -> other).

Comment: This is for problems that the OP can no longer reproduce, not for problems where the OP can still reproduce them but where they didn't provide enough information in the question for anyone *else* to reproduce them.  For situations where the OP simply didn't provide the information to reproduce it you'd want to go with unclear or the reason I posted (or a custom one, as you mentioned, but that's generally not necessary).