# Should we close old questions that have no answers, limited views and OP has already indicated they have moved on

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Regarding: [Customize toolbar styles for UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40790750/1690217)

This question is very old and has attracted limited views, limited comments and no answers.

> I write both UWP and Xamrin apps and haven't come across this as an issue, but to be fair haven't come across such a requirement either, so because I don't have an app with this issue it's hard to setup the scenario that demonstrates the error condition, and therefor hard to prove the solution if one is found.

My first thought is that this question should be closed, OP has moved on and the rest of the community have pretty much dismissed it, is that a valid reason for closure on it's own?

In this case should I use *Needs details or clarity* as the reason to close?

- My issue with this is that I would need more detail from OP to setup the scenario just to reproduce the issue, it seems highly specific to OP's code base.

Other than that, this question is well formed, and even researched. If it was not in my content area I would probably vote it up to gain attention.

I'm just starting to take these moderation tasks a bit more seriously, so I am interested in feedback on how others would approach this scenario.

I've had a look through this post: [Should we close a question that can't be answered?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351732/1690217), that lead me towards the "needs debugging help" path, but it does have some code, and if this went into the queue for that reason it would probably be left open because it appears to have enough code, on the surface.

- [Should we close a question that can't be answered?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351732/1690217)

Or is this just another candidate for [Should we have a more specific close reason for vague debugging questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258685/1690217)

Comment: If the question can't be adequately answered with the provided details, it should be closed. That's the only thing to keep in mind.

Comment: I think we should differentiate between questions that *can* be answered and questions that *cannot* be answered. I agree that it's sometimes hard to judge but at least we know there are two categories of questions. A lot of questions that cannot be answered simply lack details: "I get an error." - these should be closed until relevant details are added. Some questions do list relevant details "I get error X when I do Y, under these circumstances. I tried A, B, and C but cannot solve it". This question can potentially be answered. It might take months or years but t think it should stay open.

Comment: That's where the subject matter comes into it, Xamarin and UWP have evolved so much since 2016 that I feel this specific question is probably less likely to get solved because these types of styling issues are solved in fundamentally different ways now. I did vote to close and quickly retract my vote specifically because of your point @VLAZ

Comment: No. We close questions when they are off-topic. The question being old _doesn't make the post off-topic_.

Comment: Just because the original asker is no longer interested in the question doesn't mean that no one else is. As Martijn said, we only close questions if they are unsuitable for this site. Time doesn't factor into any of our decisions.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller: that the technology having moved on makes it less likely to get answers also doesn't matter. As the recent issues with finding COBOL developers to help fix aging unemployment registration systems in the States shows, sometimes you need to find help with outdated tech.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  I would have expected that question to have been auto deleted, is there a bug in my understanding of the auto delete system?

Comment: @IanRingrose: there seems to be a bug in your understanding of the auto delete system; you could try debugging it with the [full rules for auto-deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba), perhaps? (the post has more than 1 comment, which makes it exempt from the roomba).

Comment: The meta effect has downvoted the question to the point that it is now eligible for auto-deletion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. We close questions when they are off-topic. The question being old *doesn't make the post off-topic*.

Just because the author has moved on doesn't mean the problem wasn't real and that no-one else has the same issue. Or that someone may one day post a helpful answer that solves the issue. The goal of the site is to help future visitors with the same problem, after all.

If the question is not otherwise problematic (lacking debugging details, being too vague, etc.), then we leave the question open. Age doesn't matter, the author no longer being active or interested doesn't either.